Download Survey Data from kobotoolbox server using R
To automate the downloading of survey data from R, I used the below code:--
library(KoboconnectR)

token <- get_kobo_token(
  url="eu.kobotoolbox.org", 
  uname = username, 
  pwd = password
)
data_response <- kobotools_api(
  url = "eu.kobotoolbox.org", 
  simplified = T, 
  uname = username, 
  pwd = password
)

But my code is returning an error. I am getting a valid response for my token, but when I am running the 2nd line it shows:-
data_response <- kobotools_api(
  url = "eu.kobotoolbox.org", 
  simplified = T, 
  uname = username, 
  pwd = password
)
Downloading: 64 kB     Error in parsed$results[[i]] : subscript out of bounds


Is there an API resource page for kobotools?  You should be able to find the proper way to form a request there.
